# Javascript: Best event to use to call function for any change in text area?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want a `function` to be called whenever there is **any change** within my `text area`, i.e. char typed, removed, cut, pasted etc.

Currently I am using:

```
onkeyup || onmousemove = function();
```

This seems to only be calling `onmousemove`, what can I use to call my function on **ANY** change to the textarea.

I am creating this JS as a `string` to add it as a parameter to the creation of a text_area using `codeigniter`as described [here](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) at form_input section

e.g:

```
$js= 'onkeyup || onmousemove = "function()"';

echo text_area('name', " ", $js);
```

Comment: possibly you need [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you are looking for something like that or not ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to combine multiple HTML attribute assignment, you have to do them separately. Try:

```
text_input('name', ' ', 'onkeyup="function()" onmousemove="function()"');
```

Comment: I don't know what the `text_area()` function does. I guess it's part of some library for generating HTML. You'll have to check its documentation to see how you supply multiple event handlers.

Comment: That seems to be PHP, not Javascript. Add the PHP tag and a tag for the framework that you're using.

Comment: it just creates a textarea as it would in html

Comment: You can't assign multiple HTML attributes with the same value. You need to do them seperately: `onkeyup=function() onmousemove=function()`

Comment: This isn't JS, it's PHP and HTML. See my updated answer.

Comment: thanks, when I do this, now only the first event is being called?

Comment: Like I said, you need to read the documentation of the framework. I don't know that function, I'm just guessing. Maybe you can give it multiple attribute arguments.

Comment: If you add the framework to your tags, maybe someone who knows it will see the question and be able to answer better.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in mine. This helped me loads! how can I add oncut and onpaste to this also, I tried but only the 1st 2 work

Comment: How many times do I have to say that I don't know the framework you're using?

Comment: But if it allows you to assign two event handlers, I can't imagine why it wouldn't allow you to assign as many as you want in the same way. It's just sticking that into the HTML, so it should be the same as if you'd written it directly into the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give `textarea` an `id` say `myId` and bind events to it to trigger `handler`.

```
var element = document.getElementById("myId");
var myEvents = "oninput onchange onkeyup onpaste".split(" ");
var handler = function (e) {

};

for (var i=0, len = myEvents.length; i < len; i++) {
    element.addEventListener(myEvents[i], handler, false);
}
```

Comment: paste should be used to catch pasted content "input change blur keyup paste"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

**Example**

```
<textarea id='textarea1'>data</textarea>
```

//....................

```
$("textarea").bind('input propertychange', function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Note: Use jquery plugin

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/51eaz4dm/)**

If you want to prevent simultaneous triggers then use the below code

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

//.......

```
var text = "";
$("#textarea").on("change keyup paste", function() {
    var Val = $(this).val();
    if(Val == text) {
        return; //prevent multiple simultaneous triggers
    }

    text = Val;

    alert("changed!");
});
```

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/rw44bn10/)**